# Access another classes data from within class x

Tags: php, class

[image]

Ok i've been working in MVC for a few months now and it really taught me a huge amount on OOP however one thing is still foxing me... i don't know if i should or should not be able to do it...

In the photo I uploaded each of the blue represents a class, and the numbers represent the order of flow.

My question is: 
In the photo, can the class Load access data and or method from the Model? The class "Control" holds the objects: Model, Authenticate and Load.

I know about extending a class and then accessing the parent of the extension.. parent::something()  but this is a different thing all together..

EG:
in the "Control" i can access the model easily once I have created the object:

```
$modelData = $this -> model -> model_someFuntion($param);
```

However in the control I might have a public var named as:

```
public $controlContent1 = 'pigs can fly in parallel universe 110284';
```

Now once in the model, can I access the $controlContent1 var from the control without first passing the var to the model?

Comment: The model should not need to know about the Controller, so you have to pass any information you want the Model to process.

Comment: Yea I know but my specific question is, is it possible?

Comment: not unless the Model gets hold of the Controller instance. Equally broken alternative: make it a static property.

Comment: Ok thanks. That all I needed to know :)